# docker php container with wkhtmltopdf missing /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Tags: php, docker, macos, docker-compose, apple-m1

Trying to run php:8.0.12-fpm with docker on new mac pro with m1.
And cannot make run in php container wkhtmltopdf.

my php Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM arm64v8/php:8.0-fpm

USER root

# change user and groups ids
RUN usermod --uid=1000 www-data && \
    groupmod --gid=1000 www-data && \
    # fix permissions
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/


RUN apt update && apt install -y libxrender1 && apt install -y libfontconfig1 && apt install -y libfontconfig

RUN curl "https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz" -L -o "wkhtmltopdf.tar.xz" \
    && tar Jxvf wkhtmltopdf.tar.xz \
    && mv wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf


USER www-data
```

when trying to run wkhtmltopdf always getting `qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory`

Also somewhere read that need to install like this:

```
RUN apt-get install -y libfontconfig wkhtmltopdf
```

But then lots of options are not supported (like `--footer-font-size`)

Also tried to build `FROM php:8.0-fpm`.. nothing changes..

Comment: I have the same issue !

Answer (score 0):

Add --platform=linux/amd64 to the FROM line of the docker file.

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 php:8.0-fpm
```

If the build process starts by requesting the base image to be larm64v8/php:8.0-fpm or php:8.0-fpm, the resulting base image will have /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, indicating that everything is being emulated as x86_64 on the ARM64 CPU via qemu-x86_64. Therefore, if it is possible to start from an ARM64 image and compile any software that cannot be installed as ARM64 binaries within the container during the build process, it is likely that the subsequent container run on an M1-based Mac will be faster.